# Error al ejecutar el developer menu. Something went wrong loading developermenu.xml (GeneXus16 u4)

Tags: genexus

Se ejecuta en la aplicación de Genexus correctamente pero al abrir el developer menu no carga los objetos diseñados en la aplicación. Antes saltaba un error de Autentificacion con IIS hacia al BD, por lo que cambie la configuracion de algunas de las caracteristicas de windows. Abra causado algun tipo de problema eso?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Que quiere decir "se ejecuta en la aplicación de genexus correctamente" ? Creo que le falta un poco de info a la pregunta y especificar bien cual es el error que te da. Podrias ayudarte con capturas descriptivas. Gracias